# No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created a 'db.php' file where I make a connection to my db:

```
$db_user = 'usprojus';
$db_pass = 'xxxxxx';
$db_host = 'localhost';
// Verbinden
$dblink = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
// Datenbank "myproject" auswaehlen
// Entspricht "USE myproject;"
$selected = mysqli_select_db($dblink, 'myproject');
if (!$selected) {
    die ('Cannot use DB : '.mysqli_error($dblink));
}
mysqli_set_charset($dblink, 'utf8');
```

In order to test that is working I am trying to get data from my 'users' table:

```
require_once('db.php'); 

// Get all the data from the "users" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
or die(mysql_error());  


// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo 'user_id: '.$row['user_id'].'<br />';
    echo 'date_registered: '.$row['date_registered'].'<br />'; 
    echo 'last_login: '.$row['last_login'].'<br />';
    echo 'username: '.$row['username'].'<br />';
    echo 'email: '.$row['email'].'<br />';
    echo 'password: '.$row['password'].'<br />';
    echo 'photo: '.$row['photo'].'<br />';
    echo 'description: '.$row['description'].'<br />';
    echo 'notify: '.$row['notify'].'<br />';

}
```

But I get this error in the browser:

> No database selected

For the life of me I cannot figure out where the problem lies.

Sorry, I know this is a newbie question, and it seems it has been posted here several times. But I could not figure it out.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: @fred-ii why would you mark this as a duplicate 4 years after it has been asked??

Comment: See this Q&A https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345095/1415724 it will answer your above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are connecting to the database using the `mysqli` functions, but your query is using a `mysql` function.

Try switching your query to the `mysqli` function:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked but I had to amend it to `$result = mysqli_query($dblink, "SELECT * FROM users")`

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing up [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`mysql_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions.

I.e. `mysqli_connect`, `mysqli_select_db`, `mysqli_set_charset` *but* then `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` in your second file.

Choose one.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should use `mysqli_query()` (see [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php))

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
```

In your `db.php` you are connecting with the improved MySQL extension (mysqli).

But in your while loop you use the old MySQL extension.